# mysql php update submission error

Tags: php, html, mysql

here is my update link

**editprofile.php?no=abc**

and link us

```
<a href="editprofile.php?no=<?php echo $row['no'];?>">edit</a>
```

I need to change the **name** base on this **row no**

the php code is

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$dbhost = '';
$dbuser = '';
$dbpass = '';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
   $no=$_GET['no'];
   $name=$_POST['name'];

$sql = "UPDATE tabel_name
    SET name='$name'
    WHERE no='$no'";

mysql_select_db('database_name');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Updated data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
}
?>

<form>
<input id="edit" name="name" value="">
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

so I need to know how to change the name with new name based on no, I mean it goes to the row, based on no and rewrite the name based on new input name and redirect to the base page. **The form is ok, but when I click in the link or press submit, it gives a blank entry in mysql field of name. If there is any data before edit, it rewrite and give a blank value.**

Comment: *Code Full Of Errors* Dusty.

Comment: Where is `</form>` ? And, please don't say it is typo mistake.

Comment: ow it was writing problem, sorry

Comment: You really shouldn't use the deprecated mysql_*-functions. Your code is also wide-open for SQL-injections. There goes your database!

Comment: Where is `method="POST"` in `<form>` ?

Comment: Please do not use `msql` functions to connect to the database. These functions are deprecated since PHP 5.5 and removed in PHP 7. Try using PDO or mysqli instead. For more info : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php?rq=1

Comment: yeah, its working now.....@Nana Partykar

Comment: *You only solved your problem.* Good. @ShuvoShuvo